# build application react Native and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, react-native

I am new to React-Native that show the  users live on map language and would like to build a mobile application in which Back-end built in Ruby on Rails ?language What is the best way to do that or what resources can you learn from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question might need some more focus but I'll help you out here anyway.

So if you want to connect your mobile app(React Native) with your back end(Rails), you'll need to use Rails API. With API you can connect your back end to countless devices like web(React or anything else), mobile, etc.

So what you want to learn/research is Rails API.

There are plenty of books, courses, and blog posts about it on the internet.

Comment: did you have any idea how can show users live on map?

Comment: I'm not really sure how I would approach that, but maybe something with ActionCable to keep track of users. Have a look at the ActionCable in rails, maybe it's the thing you are looking for,